# Debugar script's PHP

Tags: php, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app Android e nessa app eu faço alguns acessos ao BD (MySQL - Hostinger) através de chamadas, de dentro do código Android , a arquivos PHP via browser.

Porém as vezes tenho problemas com os dados que estão sendo passados do Android para o PHP e assim, **queria saber se alguém sabe como debuggar esses arquivos PHP para que eu possa encontrar os possíveis problemas.**

Ou seja quando o Android executar o link do arquivo PHP que encontra-se hospedado na hostinger que eu consiga debuggar esse aquivo.

É possível? ou eu só consigo debugar esse PHP localmente?

Answer (score 0):

Se você inserir esse trecho no seu código

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

O PHP é forçado a mostrar os erros do sistema, aí você consegue fazer a análise.